# Pooling, Client Checked out, idleTimeoutMillis

Tags: node-postgres

This is my understanding after reading the [Documents](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool):

1. Pooling, like many other DBs, we have only a number of allowed connections, so you guys all line-up and wait for a free connection returned to the pool. (a connection is like a token in a sense)
2. at any given time, number of active and/or available connections is controlled in the range of 0-`max`.
3. `idleTimeoutMillis` said is "milliseconds a client must sit idle in the pool and not be checked out before it is disconnected from the backend and discarded." Not clear on this. Generally supposed when a client say a web app has done its CRUD but not return the connection voluntarily believed is **idle**. `node-postgres` will start the clock, once reaches the number of milliseconds will take the connection back to the pool for next client. So what is **not be checked out before it is disconnected from the backend and discarded?**

Say `idleTimeoutMillis: 100`, does it mean this connection will be literally disconnected (log-out) after idle for 100 millisecond? If yes then it's not returning to the pool and will result in frequent login connection as the doc said below:

> Connecting a new client to the PostgreSQL server requires a handshake
> which can take 20-30 milliseconds. During this time passwords are
> negotiated, SSL may be established, and configuration information is
> shared with the client & server. Incurring this cost every time we
> want to execute a query would substantially slow down our application.

Thanks in advance for the stupid questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry this question was not answered for so long but I recently came across a bug which questioned my understanding of this library too.

Essentially when you're pooling you're saying to the library you can have a maximum of X connections to the Database simultaneously open. So every request that comes into a CRUD API for example will open a new connection and you will have a total of X requests possible as each request opens a new connection. Now that means as soon as a request comes in it 'checks out' a connection from the pool. This also means another request cannot use this connection as it is currently blocked by another request.

So in order to let's say 'reuse' the same connection when one request is done with that connection you have to release it and say it's ready to use again 'checking out'. Now when another request comes in it is able to use this connection and do the aforementioned query.

`idleTimeoutMillis` this variable to me is very confusing to me and took a while to get my head around. When there is an open connection to a DB which has been released or 'checked out' it is in an IDLE state, which means that anyone wanting to make a request can make a request with this connection as it is not being used. This variable says that when a connection is in an IDLE state how long do we wait until we can close this connection. For various things this may be used. Obviously having open DB connections requires memory and so forth so closing them might be beneficial. Also when autoscaling - let's say you been at max requests/second and and you're using all DB conns then this is useful to keep IDLE connections open for a bit. However if this is too long and you scale down then you can run into prolonged memory as each IDLE connection will require some memory space.

The benefit of this is when you have an open connection and just send a query with it you don't need to re-authenticate with the DB it's authenticated and ready to go.